# Angularjs scope variable in nested http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem accessing to a scope variable defined in a nested $http.get. This is my controller code (it's related to a partial `$routeProvider`)

```
    //Content controller
app.controller('Content', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=' + $routeParams.slug).success(function(res) {
        $scope.post = res[0];
        document.querySelector('title').innerHTML =  res[0].title.rendered + ' | Going Solo ';
        console.log(res);
        $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[artists]=' + $scope.post.pure_taxonomies.artists[0].slug + '&exclude=' + $scope.post.id).success(function(res) {
            if (res.length > 1) {
                $scope.related = res;               
            }
            else {
                $scope.related = res[0];                
            }
            console.log(res);
        }); 
    }).error(function(res, status) {
        if (status === 404) {
            $scope.is404 = true;
            document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'Page not found | Going Solo';
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Error: ' + res[0].message;
        }
    });
}]);
```

Basically I want to retrieve all the songs related to the one that is showed in my content controller (the first `$http.get`). To link all the songs I use a custom taxonomy called “artists”. Of course I need this to be asynchronous so I do a new `$http.get` inside the first one. In this request I filter for the taxonomy slug of the current post (`$scope.post.pure_taxonomies.artists[0].slug`) plus I add a filter to exclude the post itself by adding its ID. This is working correctly by looking at the console log. It returns an array(1) for the first request and an array(2) for the second requests (with the correct data).

The problem is by the time I try to access in my partials to the second `$http.get`.
If I try this `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="songrel in related">
    <div ng-bind-html="songrel.title.extended"></div>
</div>
```

Nothing is showed. It simple doesn't enter in this cycle, so I guess he doesn't recognize `data.related`. What am I missing?

Comment: It can't find `data.related` because there's no $scope.data variable declared. Try just `related`.

Comment: Now it enters in the cycle, but my data are still not displayed. I don't get why, since the path is correct

Comment: basically this is the page where you can find the console.log http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/tracks/paperwhite-human-nature

Comment: you have a couple errors in your console, most notably, you're trying to log `rel` which doesn't exist and that is an unhandled error so it's probably the reason why it breaks

Comment: tryed with `res` but still doesn't work

Comment: now it works, I guess the caching wasn't helping me, quitted the browser and it's fine now

Comment: if you add your comment as answer I set them as valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find `data.related` because there's no $scope.data variable declared. Try just `related`, i.e.

```
<div ng-repeat="songrel in related">
    <div ng-bind-html="songrel.title.extended"></div>
</div>
```